# Quagga bgpd and static routes

Tags: networking, quagga

I have a route that is both directly connected to a router as well as received via iBGP. With quagga, if I telnet to bgpd and run `show ip bgp`, I can see the route in the table as an iBGP route and a directly connected route, however the directly connected route is of course the one that is preferred.

When I take down the directly connected route by bringing down the interface, the directly connected route is not removed from the bgp table and it is still preferred. In the kernel routing table, there is no longer any entry for the route. How do I make sure the routing tables update properly when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

should be as easy as neighbor peer shutdown...

What command are you issuing to the Quagga system to down the BGP peer?

Comment: Kelly: The command `unplug cable` ;-)